# Making Excel list more clearer to see the difference between the cells

Tags: excel

In my list in Excel I have in Column A following data:

```
Cell A1 = GG-10000
Cell A2 = GG-10000
Cell A3 = GG-10005
Cell A5 = GG-10047
cell A6 = GG-10047
Cell A7 = GG-10047
Cell A8 = GG-10050
Cell A9 = GG-10050
Cell A10 = GG-10100
```

and so one...

Can someone tell me how to bold the lines as below

```
cell A1 = GG-10000 (this need to be in bold)
Cell A2 = GG-10000 (this need to be in bold)
Cell A3 = GG-10005
Cell A5 = GG-10047(this need to be in bold)
Cell A6 = GG-10047(this need to be in bold)
Cell A7 = GG-10047(this need to be in bold)
Cell A8 = GG-10050
Cell A9 = GG-10050
Cell A10 = GG-10100(this need to be in bold)
```

So the idea is that I can see the difference between the different numbers.

Many thanks

Robin

Comment: Do you want cell to be bold when the data is different from the previous row? Not clear from the example, why not bold for A8 & A9?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting.

If you have Office 365 Excel you can use this formula:

```
=ISODD(MATCH(A1,UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")),0))
```

[image]

[image]

- `UNIQUE =>` a list of the unique entries
- `MATCH =>` position of each individual entry in the unique list
- `ISODD =>` returns alternating boolean when the entry changes

If you don't have these Excel O365 functions, I'd suggest you develop a VBA routine or use a helper column to do something similar.

Here's an example of a "helper column"

- I'll use column `B`, but you can use any column anywhere; and you can hide it.

  B1: 1
  B2: =IF(A2=A1,B1,-B1)  and fill down

Conditional Format formula:

```
=B1=1
```

Since the CF `Applies to` range is unchanged, that will still be the range that gets formatted.

Comment: Dear Ron, tx for your help. This is exactly what I need but I do not have 365 functions, so it is not working and I do not know how to make this with a VBA routine..do you have an other suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: @THEHOOD In that case, what have you tried so far as using a helper column or a VBA routine for conditional formatting, as I suggested?

Comment: I tried a helper column but there is no formula in Excel to bold cells, as for VBA I have no idea to begin...

Comment: @THEHOOD The helper column should "switch" as does the data; then your CF format refers to the helper column. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with a helper column then in cell `B1` put `1`.

and in cell `B2`:

`=IF(A2=A1,B1,B1+1)`

which you shall copy down. Afterwards, for A1:A9 range apply conditional formatting like below:
[image]

The outcome if implemented correctly will look like below.

[image]

Comment: Tx very much for your help!! That did it.